# Is there a difference between hacking and edging your chances?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, questions

If a user asks us about a way to better his/her abilities in a game do we flag it or answer it.

For example: If the user wanted a way to increase their FOV in a game which would increase their chances of winning but the option to increase the the FOV wasn't directly implemented into the game what would we do.

Now with the FOV example you could zoom in and out of the window resize the window ect... There's tricks to do things like these

Now I know the difference when it comes to things like modifying a games server illegally to increase stats and unlocks ect...

Also things like godmode would be outright cheating

But things like my example do they count to as illegal/off-topic/against the site

Comment: Count for what?

Comment: @frank oops I'll fix that, I meant so do they count as illegal/off-topic/against the site

Comment: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10317/cheats-in-multiplayer-games-are-banned-but-what-is-a-cheat

Comment: Do you have any real examples (i.e. links to such questions)?

Comment: @CamelCase gave me that link that helped me out, just need to close this post now, thanks guys